# Run a Python function for x seconds?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have a data stream that I need parse and extract values from, create a list of those values and append them to a list in a nested list fashion, e.g. mainList[[firstExtractedValue],[SecondExtractedValue]...]. The creation of the mainList must run in 15 minutes segments, after which I iterate over mainList and create a second list. If I call sleep() or threading.Timer the list is not created because both run AFTER a given period of time. I need the function to run FOR a given period of time (i.e it needs to create the list FOR 15 minutes).

Comment: Why do you want a certain *time*, rather than a (much simpler) certain *number*?

Comment: To demand an execution should last a specific amount of time makes no sense. What you probably want is: Start the execution of this task ever 15 minutes.

Comment: You can check the time that you start, and check in the loop to see if 15 minutes have passed.  see datetime module

Comment: How about you parse/extract/add items in an iterative manner, and every N items check the time that has passed since the beginning - after 15 minutes, perform the list rotation. Wouldn't this approach work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The data stream is asynchronous, in any given 15 minute segment I can receive 1000 or 10,000 values. Also the algorithm I am using to calculate the second list requires the amount time and not number of occurrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just periodically check the time, and end after 15-minutes, no? Something like:

```
import datetime
def func(maxrt):
    stop = datetime.datetime.now() + maxrt
    while datetime.datetime.now() < stop:
        # do stuff

func(datetime.timedelta(minutes=15))
```

Comment: et al   Yikes! Somehow I missed using the datetime module.  I think you all are right. I am a bit of a noob with python. I believe your methods should work. Thx.

Comment: No worries.  It's easy to get too focused and miss the easy stuff.